# Filter tcpdump file AFTER capturing

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, filter

I captured a really big tcpdump file which now always crashes my wireshark. It was captured with no filters and I need to apply some afterwards to make the file smaller.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use the following command:

```
tcpdump -r your_input_file.pcap -w your_output_file.pcap "your_filter"
```

Tcpdump will read the input file, apply the filter, and then write the output file. You need just to come up with the right filter.

Answer (score 1):

Try [netsniff-ng](http://netsniff-ng.org/), it sequentially processes the pcap unlike Wireshark, which tries to load everything into RAM.